# ERROR Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebView, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native

When I run this command

```
npm ls react-native-webview
```

It shows this

├─┬ react-native-linkedin@2.1.1 │ └── react-native-webview@7.0.5 └─┬ react-native-simple-twitter@3.0.6   └── react-native-webview@8.2.1

I tried to force them to use the same react-native-view but it didn't work.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use react-native-linkedin and react-native-simple-twitter to login and register users with LinkedIn and Twitter, but they use different webview version. When I try, I check this error